# How to view and get access to custom shapes in a document?

Tags: ms-word

I have a template which is used for generation of documents. I have come across a code in a software we use which switches between custom shapes depending on a country.

```
If cboCountry.Text = "USA" Then
            doc.Shapes("Logo-US").Visible = True
            doc.Shapes("Logo-Canada").Visible = False
            UpdatePropertyValue("color", {"ColourColor"})
        Else
            doc.Shapes("Logo-US").Visible = False
            doc.Shapes("Logo-Canada").Visible = True
            UpdatePropertyValue("colour", {"ColourColor"})
        End If
```

However, I cannot find these shapes anywhere in the document. How do I get access to these shapes?

This question is mainly aimed at learning MS Word capabilities. The real problem I'm facing here is that Canada is default value and when I have the Canada shape disabled and US enabled the US shapes ends up being lower (below initial Canada Shape) in the document than the initial position of the Canada shape.

Comment: The shapes would be located where they appear and would likely be anchored close to that.

Comment: @macropod  Right clicking on the existing visible shapes doesn't proved any option to view a "Shapes Manager" or where it is stored.

Comment: With Word's formatting display turned 'on', when you click on a visible shape, Word displays an anchor symbol at whichever paragraph the shape is anchored to...

Comment: Just to close this. SOLUTION :
Right click Picture Shape and select Format Shape
In the navigation pane on the right, click the paint can at the top of the menu
Under 'Fill' select Picture or texture fill
Click insert under picture source and select the image you want
Than save it